# Possible to use tags/buttons as exposed filters?

Tags: views

I have a view that will be a grid of a dozen content types. I would like to have a tag-like button or text link above the view of content to allow the user to toggle / filter between what content type they wish to see. I know that exposed filters allows you to use a dropdown or auto-complete, but is this possible with using tags as buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have something like this, what is provided by the [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) module (Drupal 7) or [Facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets) For Drupal 8.

[image]
Image copied from: https://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-2-faceted-search (explanation of Facet API combined with Search API).  It should however also work with the Drupal core search system. (I only used it with [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api))

> The Facet API module allows site builders to easily create and manage
>   faceted search interfaces. In addition to the UI components that come
>   out of the box, themers and module developers can build their own
>   widgets that can optionally be contributed back to Drupal.org. Facet
>   API works with the core Search, Search API, and Apache Solr Search
>   Integration modules (including Acquia Search) meaning that code and
>   configuration can be reused as-is with the most popular search
>   solutions available to Drupal. Refer to the documentation for more
>   details.

Each facet will be exposed as a block, that you can place anywhere in your site from the block administration page.

Comment: Great, this is just what I'm looking for

Comment: Here is another good tutorial for setting up the Search API with Facets http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/drupal-7-views-with-faceted-filters-without-apachesolr/

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easier option than setting up the Search API, you could just use Views Better Exposed Filters. https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters

Comment: The facet API module claims to support core search. So setting up search API is not required.

Comment: @Neograph734, you're right but currently its still under development for supporting the core search in D8. https://www.drupal.org/node/2877989#comment-12137409